# TypeError: ABC is not a function, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, sequelize.js

I have 2 file `MainClass.js` and `router.js`. `MainClass.js` file contains method `getSomeData` which I want to `access in router.js file.`

I do not want to access properties in the mainClass object from outside the MainClass class. Instead I want to add a method named something like `getProcessedData` to the MainClass class, and that method should `delegate through the _coolData property.`

However I am getting below error with current approach

Error

```
`TypeError:  _coolData.getProcessedData is not a function`
```

MainClass.js file

```
    
// main class

class MainClass {

    constructor(conn) 
      { this._coolData = new Play_Me(sequelize, options.schema);}

 getProcessedData()
    { return this._coolData.getSomeData() }

}

class Play_Me extends Model {
    big_Data;
    conn;
    
    constructor(conn, schema) 
     { super(conn, schema, "Play_Me");}
    
    async getSomeData()
      {// Business Logic } 

module.exports = MainClass;
```

router.js file

```
const _coolData = require('../db/MainClass'); 

router.get('/sandy/abc', express.json(), (req, res) => {
    _coolData.getProcessedData()
        .then(
            error => { console.log(error); res.status(500).send({ success: false, error } ) });
});
```

Comment: `_coolData` is pointing to the class, you need to instantiate it first. `new _coolData().getProcessedData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"_coolData" is not constructed yet. It is the definition of a class - the blueprints - but does not contain the methods itself yet.
Try constructing with the `new` keyword and calling `getProcessedData()` on the new instance.

```js
const _CoolData = require('../db/MainClass'); 
const _coolData = new _CoolData();
_coolData.getProcessedData()
//... other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create an instance of your class with `new` keyword. right now I think you should do this:

```
// router.js
const MainClass= require('../db/MainClass'); 

const _coolData= new MainClass();
router.get('/sandy/abc', express.json(), (req, res) => {
    _coolData.getProcessedData()
        .then(
            error => { console.log(error); res.status(500).send({ success: false, error } ) });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are exporting the class and not an object of that class. As your `getProcessedData` function is an intense function and not a class function, it is not accessible.

To make it accessible, you either want to export an initialized object (i.e. `module.exports = new MainClass()`) or you make `getProcessedData` a class function by adding the `static` keyword.